# Call GnuPG from Firefox add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, gnupg

I'm writing an add-on for Firefox. I want to know what is the best way to use GnuPG from the add-on.

I have tried several Node.js modules and does not work either within the add-on because it can not find its dependencies

Comment: I would suggest that you provide us with your code, a [mcve] that duplicates the problem you are seeing.

Comment: I don't have any working code, and the answer is use a webextension not an add-on

Comment: The point is that you do have code that you are trying to get working. The code you have "does not work either within the add-on because it can not find its dependencies". The choice of using a WebExtension, or [another type of add-on](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/introduction-to-firefox-add-ons/13574/introduction#t=201609290133319078047), depends on multiple factors.

Comment: The problem was the Window object, is mandatory for openpgpjs

Comment: Then you can set the `window` variable to an appropriate `<window>` element.

Comment: What [kind of Firefox extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons) are you making ([WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) [[tag:firefox-webextensions]],  [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) [[tag:fiirefox-addon-sdk]], [Bootstraped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions) [[tag:firefox-addon-restartless]], or [Overlay/XUL/Legacy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions) [[tag:fiirefox-addon-overlay]]/[[tag:xul]])? Please [edit] the appropriate tag into your question.

Comment: i solved the issue developing a webextension

Comment: What, *exactly*, was shown in the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (Ctrl-Shift-J, or Cmd-Shift-J on OSX) when you tried to call GnuPG?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the issue developing a webextension.

Webstaensions can access to the Window object, i was talkig with a developer of the Mailvelope add-on and he suggest the switch to a webextension, they are planning that switch for they add-on

Comment: Any Firefox add-on can access `<window>` elements (of which there are many). In other add-on types, if you need a `window` variable pointing to a `<window>` element, it is your responsibility to set the `window` variable to the `<window>` you desire. There are many questions/answers on Stack Overflow explaining this/how to do so. The failure to do so is a common mistake. WebExtensions is much more limited. In most instances, you only have access to a single `<window>` object.